# ES6 Arrow function without curly braces

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

I'm having a hard time understanding the following ES6 syntax. I read the docs quite a bit and it seems like there is more than one change happening here:

```
const renderInput = props =>
  <div>
    <label>{props.placeholder}</label>
  </div>
```

Would the above be equivalent to:

```
const renderInput = function renderInput(props) {
  return <div>
           <label>{props.placeholder}</label>
         </div>
}
```

?

Comment: That isn't ES6. Might be JSX.

Comment: Yes, but you need to wrap the HTML with backticks. And string parameters need a leading `$`... `${param}`

Comment: @Mottie yes it's the same ?

Comment: @Mottie This is JSX, not HTML, so, no, he does not.

Comment: LOL ok, *now* we have the appropriate tags in place.

Comment: if you have one return value no need to add return.

Comment: Were you asking about the lack of **brackets** around the function's body, the lack of **parentheses** around `props`, or both? Asking b/c the accepted answer answers the first, but your title mentions the second explicitly (which hasn't been answered yet, curiously enough -- though the answer is similar: [if your function only has one parameter, no parens are needed](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/javascriptarrowfunctions.shtml)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. When you have only one *expression*, and it's the expression you wish to return from the function, you may omit the curly brackets.

Since `<div><label>{props.placeholder}</label></div>` is, in fact, a single expression (it gets transpiled to `React.createElement(......)` or something like that), and you wish to return it from `renderInput`, that is indeed how you use the no-brackets version of the arrow function.

If you had wished to use variables or do some other computation (conditions, for loops, etc), you wouldn't have been able to omit the brackets.

Comment: so it would indeed be `const renderInput = function renderInput(props)`, repeating `renderInput` twice ?

Comment: You can only use that function name in recursion anyway. The browser's devtools would assign the name of the `const` if the function has no name anyway, so the two are almost equivalent. Strictly speaking, it's equivalent to `const renderInput = function(props) {` not `function renderInput(props)`.

Comment: @softcode: You might want to read [Named function expressions demystified](https://kangax.github.io/nfe/)